# Solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = (x-y)/(x+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

> $$\frac { { d }y }{ { d }x } =\frac { x-y }{ x+y } $$

It is homogeneous, thus let $y = vx$. From this, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} + v$

Thus,

$v'x + v = (1-v)/(1+v)$ thus,

$\frac{2}{1-v} + \ln(v - 1) = \ln(x) + C$.

Which by substituion,

$\frac{2x}{x-y} + \ln(y - x) = 2\ln(x) + C$

But I cant get it any further

Comment: Haven't you already solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { x-y }{ x+y } \\ \frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { 1-\frac { y }{ x }  }{ 1+\frac { y }{ x }  } \\ y=zx\\ z^{ \prime  }x+z=\frac { 1-z }{ 1+z } \\ z^{ \prime  }x=\frac { 1-z }{ 1+z } -z=\frac { 1-2z-z^{ 2 } }{ 1+z } \\ \int { \frac { 1+z }{ 1-2z-z^{ 2 } } dz } =\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } \\ -\int { \frac { 1+z }{ { z }^{ 2 }+2z-1 } dz } =\int  \frac { dx }{ x } \\ -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { d\left( z^{ 2 }+2z-1 \right)  }{ z^{ 2 }+2z-1 } =\int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } \\ \\ \ln { \left| z^{ 2 }+2z-1 \right|  } =\ln { \frac { C }{ x^{ 2 } }  } \\ z^{ 2 }+2z-1=\frac { C }{ x^{ 2 } } \\ \frac { y^{ 2 } }{ x^{ 2 } } +2\frac { y }{ x } -1=\frac { C }{ x^{ 2 } }  $$
so the answer is :

> $$\\ y^2 +2xy-x^2 =C\\ $$

Comment: Which has the explicit solution $y=-x\pm\sqrt {C+3x^2}$

Comment: You changed the $1$ to a $2$ when you flipped the sign of the denominator; it should be just $-x^2$.

Comment: @joriki,i edited it thank you)

Comment: Writing it with the explicit solution, there's an additional caveat that there are 4 distinct [global] solutions if $C$ is negative. The one with the $+$ branch, the one with the $-$ branch, and then the two that switch their branch at $x = \sqrt{-C/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your step from

$$v'x + v = (1-v)/(1+v)$$

to

$$
\frac{2}{1-v} + \ln(v - 1) = \ln(x) + C
$$

is wrong. Separating $v$ and $x$ yields

$$
v'\cdot\frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}=\frac1x\;,
$$

and then integrating leads to

$$
-\frac12\log\left(1-2v-v^2\right)=\log x+C\;,
\\
1-2v-v^2=cx^{-2}\;,
$$

and thus

$$
x^2-2xy-y^2=c\;,
$$

in agreement with Battani's answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{x-y}{x+y}
$$
The equation
$$
(y-x)\,\mathrm{d}x+(y+x)\,\mathrm{d}y=0
$$
is exact, so we just need to integrate along any path to get
$$
y^2+2xy-x^2=C
$$